# CodeIgniter get application name from url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

i am working on codeigniter to managing multiple application.

according to codeigniter this will work for multiple applications and its working perfectly

```
$application_folder = "applications/foo";
$application_folder = "applications/bar";

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
```

what i am trying to do is set application name from url and load that application

for example

```
http://localhost/mywork/myapp1/
http://localhost/mywork/myapp2/welcome

$application_folder = "applications/".$app_name;
```

and this will load app1 or whatever app name i write in the url

Thanks for Help

Comment: I don't think the URL routing functionality within CI would allow you to do this, although I'm not sure. The URL parts will be available if in the CI object (print_r($this)) but that object probably wont be available in the configuration.php (or is it settings.php, it's been so long since I last used CI) so you wont be able to change the application path I don't think. The more I think about it though the more I think I could get it to work. Just try a print_r on $this from within the settings file.

Comment: ok, had a look, the $applicationPath variable is within index.php and it's before any of the framework's loaded, what you're looking to do isn't possible. Your best bet it to give each application it's own version of index.php (call them different things) and then use mod_rewrite in a .htacees to manage with app is loaded.

Comment: Have you set up both the index.php files in the correct directories?

Comment: To do what you want you'll need a third install, placed in the root, who then reroutes to the 2 sub-installs. That's the same as saying: put each install inside its folder (one in [root]/myapp1/ and one in [root]/myapp2/), and all happens automatically

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested either of these two ideas, but they should work, and are better than messing with your index.php file.

You could create two separate index.php files (one for each application folder). Call one myapp1.php and the other myapp2.php and put them in the root directory and set the application folder in each of them correctly (and the index.php var in the config).

Your URLs would then be:

```
http://localhost/mywork/myapp1.php/welcome
http://localhost/mywork/myapp2.php/welcome
```

Or, you could create two directories called myapp1 and myapp2 in the root directory, create the standard index.php files in each and then point them to the correct application folder (this may have to be relative, or might have to be the correct server path).

Good luck.

Comment: how can i remove .php? via .htaccess

Comment: No that wouldn't work because your .htaccess file wouldn't know which .php file to route to, you would have to try the second method I suggested.